# I have super powers, now what? (or how to find good duplicates)

Tags: support, duplicate-questions, dupehammer

[How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java) has been used as a duplicate for [1,428 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/513832?lq=1). That probably indicates that it is a good canonical answer to a very common problem.

Now that I can close questions in one click, I would love to have a list of *canonical Q&A* based on how often they have been used as duplicate.

**Is there a way to search the questions that are most often linked as duplicate?**

<sub>Note: tagging as support for now - will become feature-request if not currently possible.</sub>

Comment: Maybe try using [data.se]? Or how about the [built-in advanced search](http://stackoverflow.com/help/searching)? There's also [the frequently linked tab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git?sort=frequent&pageSize=50).

Comment: I wouldn't worry about old questions.  Focus on newly-asked questions as a part of your normal interaction with the site, and close dupes as you encounter them.

Comment: Is there any practical way to just ban questions that are obvious duplicates of "how to compare strings in java" from being posted in the first place?

Answer (score 4):

For the specific tag, click on the "Frequent" tab. I believe that the questions listed there are the ones that are most frequently linked to as duplicates.

This is probably not particularly canonical however. In order to do that, I think you need a special tag like for example [c++-faq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-faq) (discussion about that tag [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252874/setting-up-a-faq-for-the-c-tag)). A few other tags have similar FAQs.

Whether such specific FAQ tags are encouraged or discouraged, I don't know. But it seems like a good thing to have for the most popular topics. So it is probably up to the high rep users for a specific tag to band together and create a canonical FAQ.

As a side note, perhaps site support for a FAQ would be a nice thing to implement. What would be needed is essentially just a restricted tag that can only be used by people with a gold badge for the specific topic. It would be a feature related to the recent change where gold badge users can instantly close duplicates.