# How to handle edits you think shouldn't have been made

Tags: discussion, edits, rollbacks

I recently [came across a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5349624/how-to-call-methods-dynamically-based-on-their-name) in which a user had gone through and edited the question and all the answers heavily. I think it was done with good intentions to make things clearer and cleaner, but I believe the edits were too broad and changed the original meaning of the question and some of the answers unnecessarily.

What's the proper way to deal with something like this?

- Revert all the edits? (But being <2K rep would be a pain, plus it's just my opinion vs. his opinion)
- Flag the question? (But nothing was wrong with the question)
- Send an @message to the editor saying I disagree? (But that just leads to my opinion vs. his opinion)
- Something else?

Comment: Personally I think this question edit *just* scrapes through and I would be inclined to keep it. The edit author changed code which is normally a no-no, but it was redundant code. The original question has changed quite a bit, but the original wasn't asked very well. Additionally the question could probably have been marked as a duplicate.

Comment: @slugster I personally disagree as the the original question was asking about calling a method in a Rails context using the `params[:action]` parameter, which has different security implications than the edit.

Comment: @slugster I noticed that this older question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/621176/how-to-dynamically-call-accessor-methods-in-ruby?lq=1) was closed as a duplicate of the newer question. Does that normally happen? Seems somewhat strange

Comment: Actually, I think in this specific case that's why the question got edited so heavily. A lot of questions are closed as a duplicate of the question I linked to in the OP - the edits to the questions and all the answers made this question more appropriate to be linked to in that way. Edit: Actually, the same guy just marked all those questions as duplicates too...

Comment: This happened to me once, so I simply rolled back the edit and left a comment that I didn't agree with the edit and explained why.

Comment: @JKillian Sometimes, if the older question is of lower quality, it's the better one to close

Comment: Editor in question here: just want to throw in that I think commenting was and is the right way to go. Of course how well that pans out depends on who the person is; personally I think I’m rather open to criticism `:)`.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Don't flag the question: moderators aren't here to deal with edit inaccuracy.

If you have editing privileges, the best thing here would be to roll back the edits, which you can do from the edit history of a post:

[image: Rollback]

Otherwise, you can use the revision dropdown given to you in the edit page:

[image: Revision menu]
[image: Revision selection]

Selecting a prior revision will show you the post's source at the time of that revision, and you can make your edits from there: a "manual" rollback.

If it's a major change, you may want to @reply the editor in comments for a discussion before taking it into your own hands (unless it's your own post: in that case, do whatever you want to it).

If it turns into an edit war, just leave: it's not worth it.

Comment: What's a(n) FHC?

Comment: @JohnY http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/247602

Comment: @canon I apologize for my dedication to clear and visible circles.

Comment: @canon How do you know Astro isn't just really good at drawing shapes? And a note **not** to -1 for silly things.

Comment: Thanks for the quality answer. I think leaving a comment is a good way to handle things - lets you see what the original editor was thinking and express why you disagree with the edits which hopefully leads to the best possible post with ideas from the two of you combined

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek FYI - it's a common joke on Meta Stack Exchange (and maybe other Metas / sites) to comment "*-1 for { silly reason xyz },*" but not actually downvote.  It's likely canon didn't downvote (or at least that was not the actual reason for the downvote).

Comment: I love **rollback**! +1

Answer (score 6):

I think the person who did the edits is hoping to make a canonical post to which frequently posted duplicates can be linked. Still, the edits are questionable. A better way would have been if he wrote a new questions Q&A style, which he then answers himself. If he wish, he can then petition to have it turned into a community wiki.

As for what to do with all those edits, I don't know enough of the specific programming language to tell. If they changed the meaning of the question or radically changed the code, they should get rollbacked. I think leaving a comment, as you did, is the sensible thing to do for now. Give him some days to come back to fix it (if needed), and then all is well. If he doesn't and you believe his changes are too radical, then rollback.

Comment: Yes, this was my intent. I’ve had my eye on this one for a while and have always tried to find a very good canonical question, but never could, so finally went and edited the most popular (and nearly oldest) one. I tend to prefer generalizing older, popular questions to making a new one (though I’m not really sure why—maybe it’s because I feel like a canonical question should be older and have a bunch of votes). Typically when I do mass canonicalization there’s a good source, but here there wasn’t. I’ll consider creating a new one in the future, though, thanks! (+1)

Comment: Not cool.  Write your own question **and especially your own answer**.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall In all fairness, you might have a point with this, whether you know it or not. For a question to turn into a "frequent" one and show up at SO's equivalent to a FAQ for the given tag, I believe it needs a lot of duplicates closed and linked to itself. Older posts may have more such duplicates already linked to them, making it more probably that they will turn into a "frequent" question. Still, this is not the right way to go and the core problem might be the bad way SO handles FAQs.

Comment: Personally I'd rather see a specific tag for such questions, such as the [tag:c++-faq] one. I'm not sure if that is the right way to go either, but it certainly generates a much more relevant FAQ than the dysfunctional "frequent" tab. More info about the C++-FAQ tag can be found in [this meta post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252874/setting-up-a-faq-for-the-c-tag).

Comment: Maybe it is relevant to create such tags for Ruby, C, Java et al?