# Reviewing First Posts - what should I do if post was handled?

Tags: discussion, review-queues

While reviewing first posts, I often receive a question like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/5550839), in which I think the question deserves a comment, recommending the user to do this or that. However, sometimes those questions are already commented on by a different user, who probably stumbled upon the question.

Having the comment made by someone else, I mark "No Action Needed."

Is this what I'm supposed to do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should upvote the comment from the other user if that comment expresses your same sentiment.

Upvoting a comment on the post counts as a review action and you will be able to press "I'm Done" after taking it ("No Action Needed" will be grayed out because you've taken an action).

For audit purposes, upvoting a comment has the same effect as leaving a new one.

[image: Upvote a comment]

As you can see, that marks it as "Reviewed," rather than "No Action Needed."

[image: Counts as a review action]

Comment: I'm disappointed. That red circle is not free-hand.

Comment: And just to add, up-voting a comment is basicly the same in the system's eyes as making a new comment.

Comment: @gunr2171 http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268339/how-to-handle-edits-you-think-shouldnt-have-been-made#comment76617_268340

Comment: Yeah, maybe we are beating that joke into the ground too much.

Comment: @gunr2171 Not necessarily: that's just my position.

Comment: Then understand that honestly no one cares if you don't use freehand circles. We all love giving people a hard time just because it's a meme. It's fine either way. So my first comment was pure sarcasm. So keep on doing whatever you feel is best.

Comment: @gunr2171 Yes, I know, which is why I'm not bothered by it: I find it funny in an ironic sense, so continue if you wish.

Comment: Why is voting up a comment a review action? The comment could say "your question is unclear" or it could say "Great first question, welcome to SO!" the audit system surely doesn't know... guess it's no worse than commenting being a review action, though.

Comment: @eddie_cat In review queues, the comment action is seen as "negative" because you are supposed to use comments to critique or request clarification from the author: voting on a comment is handled the same way leaving a new one is: if you want to edit a good question to make it better or leave a praising comment, you should do it outside of the queue.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146988/new-review-queue-first-posts is it?

Comment: @eddie_cat "Comment to leave constructive feedback feedback for the author"- "Great question!" is not constructive feedback.

Comment: That doesn't mean there's no such thing as constructive feedback, haha. It was just an example. Regardless, there are definitely useful comments you can make on posts that shouldn't be classified as "bad."

Comment: @eddie_cat But those should be made outside of the review queue: the only time where it matters that it's a negative action is during an audit, in which case it should be a good post that shouldn't need constructive criticism *from a review queue* (although it may need it from the main part of site). It's all a matter of opinion, of course.

Comment: Yeah. I've had this conversation here before, imo it's a bad design to show people the option to leave a comment as usual but force them to open a new tab to do so if they don't want to fail audits. There should either be no comment option, some visual cue that commenting in the queue is different, or else it shouldn't count as a review action.