# Allow vote changes on answers when a question is edited by the OP

Tags: discussion, feature-request

It seems like we should allow changing on answer votes when a question is edited (at least by the OP), not just when the answer is edited.

I recently downvoted an answer in which the answerer hadn't read the OP's question clearly, and responded with something that was the opposite of what the OP was trying to do. The answerer even acknowledged that this seemed to be the case in the comments.

However, presumably after reading that answer/comments, the OP edited his question to the *ask for the opposite of what he'd previously asked*, thereby rendering the now down-voted answer perfectly reasonable (and the answer that I had subsequently posted to be the one that now didn't properly address the question).

I could not remove the down-vote at the time because the *answer* hadn't been edited.

Subsequently, the answerer did edit his post and the down-vote was reversed, but it seems like it would be appropriate to allow re-voting in cases where there are substantive changes to the question, especially by the OP, as our understanding of their question is critical in terms of deciding which answers are useful or not.

Comment: IMHO it's fine as it is now. If people don't read the question properly and the OP decides to edit his question to match the answerers... that's way off of what SO is aiming for. It makes sense for answer edits, but not for question edits.

Comment: @Seth I look it this way: I down-voted because the answer didn't answer the question. The OP changed the question, invalidating the premise on which I cast the down-vote. Now my vote doesn't even represent my own opinion, and I would have liked to be able to correct that.

Comment: @NicolasHolthaus I can't see the OP editing the question to match the answer as being very common.  So to change the current design for a rare occurrence seems like the wrong approach.  If it was very common, might be worth discussing

Comment: @psubsee2003 I'm not really talking about changing questions to match answers, I agree with you on that and I'm not even sure that happened here. I'm talking about when an OP changes a question to the point that he's _effectively asking a different question_, which happens all the time.

Comment: @NicolasHolthaus if the question changes to make a previously correct answer wrong, the edit should normally be rolled back, so you don't need that feature for that case.  And for cases where the question changed to make a previously incorrect answer correct, that doesn't seem to be common.  I still don't see the need.  Perhaps if you could expand your justification to more than just a single scenario, the benefit you see might be more obvious

Comment: @psubsee2003 Maybe the part I was missing is that the OPs question edit should be rolled back. Should I be flagging that or something?

Comment: Not really flagging as it is not really an issue for moderators.  2K users have a rollback option for editing to revert to a previous revision.  Before you get to 2K, best option is to suggest the edit yourself to undo the changes but make sure your edit description is very clear  as to what and why you are doing it

Comment: @NicolasHolthaus If you want to rollback a post [you can use the dropdown in the edit mode to suggest an edit that starts as a copy of a previous revision](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268339/how-to-handle-edits-you-think-shouldnt-have-been-made/268340#268340)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This would probably cause harm.**

A far more common situation than what you describe is the OP editing the question to invalidate previously correct answers--either because the original question was incorrect or unclear, or because the OP wants help with a new problem after the original problem was solved.

The feature you propose would probably be used to remove upvotes after this happens.  This would be wrong, since the OP, not the answerers are at fault in this case.  It would discourage the people working to provide good content on the site (answering only to have the goalposts move is annoying enough already).