# Why was my edit rejected when attempting to revert a question?

Tags: discussion, edits

Earlier I attempted to roll-back [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36918566/construct-qpushbutton-with-qicon-alignleft-and-text-center-align), after the OP incorporated my answer into it and used the edit to effectively ask a different question.

I've actually [been told on meta before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320270/allow-vote-changes-on-answers-when-a-question-is-edited-by-the-op) that the right thing to do in this situation is revert the question, since the edit effectively invalidated my previous answer. Here's a [link to the review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12182748).

Why was the edit rejected?

Comment: Rollbacks aren't exactly easily done with <2k rep. I would guess that the reviewers didn't read your edit summary. (Which I did, and it looked decently clear to me.)

Comment: Thanks @Kendra, I couldn't acutally even find it, maybe for the same reason.

Comment: I've rolled the question back to the point at which it was answered. If it changes for the worse again, raise a custom moderator flag and explain what's happened.

Comment: Yeah, most of my edits where I'm trying to stop the OP from invalidating existing answers get rejected. Now I just point out in the comments that the OP should not be doing that, down voting if possible, and hoping someone with 2K+ will see and fix it.

Comment: Maybe edits from 1 rep users should get a little extra scrutiny.

Comment: @NicolasHolthaus I could see making an argument for that. (If reviewers aren't already doing that, some are I'm sure.) The problem is, when the 1 rep user is the OP of the post, it doesn't matter. The OP has full editing rights on their own post. So unlike your edit, the OP in this case didn't get reviewed period, and this probably would have slipped on by if you hadn't seen it.

Comment: @Kendra ah. Hence the impossibility of reverting the question with less than 2k rep, since it's almost always in the OPs (perceived) interest to keep the update. Maybe there should be a flag or something for this type of behavior then.

Comment: In theory, you _could_ flag other and explain the situation, but you're better off either leaving a comment, as BSMP stated, or going to chat and asking if a 2k+ user could help out. Mods would probably decline the flag, since it's something the community can fix. (Unless the OP in question has a bad habit of doing this, or your rollback goes through and they redo the edit.)

Comment: @BSMP Although this is Off topic for this particular question, I've been through your comments and reverted the only post I could find where you'd made that kind of comment. You can always bring problems up here if you have them.

Comment: Most SE reviewers reject everything you can't judge to be OK in the 2 second window that it takes for the gray on the buttons to disappear.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Because reviewers are, by and large, human and prone to making mistakes.

There was nothing wrong with your edit.

Welcome to Stack Exchange!

Comment: just one more in a long list of reasons not to attempt to help people with low quality questions...

Comment: @NicolasHolthaus: Yeah :(

Comment: The worst part is, it's all probably moot because I think the question got `meta-effected` to the point where it will be deleted anyway.

Comment: @NicolasHolthaus if the question is on topic and clear, it will not be closed (well, it shouldn't be). Even with a bunch of downvotes, unclosed questions with upvoted, accepted answers don't get auto-deleted (unless I'm mistaken). Individual delete votes by high-rep users could do away with it, but this should not happen. Good luck for [Reversal](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/95/reversal) in the long run.

Comment: @AndrasDeak: Good advice in general but I see no reason for this question to survive.

Comment: Sorry, thanks, I have zero domain knowledge. I only assumed that the question might not be worthless due to the lack of close votes and that from Nicolas's post I gathered that the majority of downvotes might be due to the meta effect. (Unrelated: early congratulations for 200k next week;)

Comment: @AndrasDeak: Woooo