# User edits code in their question to reflect suggestions made in answers

Tags: discussion, edits

My question is not a duplicate of the possible duplicate, because that question asks:  **What to do when users try to edit their question to ask another one**. I'm asking: **what to do when users try to edit code in their question such that it removes the problem from the code example**.

---

I have observed quite a few times a user(usually the newer ones) will ask a question, with a code example to illustrate their problem.

Another user will then post a answer that address the problem(s) in the asker's question. The asker will then edit the code in their question to fix the mistakes/bugs/problems in it, based upon what the answerer pointed out in their answer.

---

It could be reasonably inferred that the user in question does not fully understand how the SO site works. What is the preferred way to handle users doing such behavior, and inform them of the correct behavior? Would it be appropriate to attempt to edit and fix their question.

Comment: Leave a comment explaining that their question is useless to future visitors if it doesn't show the original problem. Rollback the post to before the edits that fixed the problematic code.

Comment: Just to clarify, does the answer posted actually answer the main question in the post?  Or is it just pointing out tangential information about the code that isn't truly relevant to the main question?

Comment: @ryanyuyu no. It answers the main question. The user then "fixes" their code example based on that answer.

Comment: If it answers the question, then my duplicate target is a good one.  The same rule applies, namely that questions shouldn't have scope-creep.  All of those edits should be rolled back to keep the answer valid.

Comment: I'm sure this is still a dupe, but the current dupe target isn't correct. Voted to reopen.

Comment: @Will Well I can't say for a fact, but I'm pretty sure that there is no dupe. Thanks for the vote.

Comment: There are plenty of posts about "chameleon questions" about edits that invalidate answers, many of which probably are close enough to be duplicate.

Comment: @Will Sure, ok. I'm really not to concerned at this point if this is marked as a dupe, as I have method for dealing with things such as this now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No need to 'edit and fix' - just roll back the question to it's original state and leave a comment explaining that you've rolled it back to keep the context of the question.

The other danger of people updating the original post in this way is that it takes the context away from the answers that have been provided, and can in some cases result in people downvoting answers that no longer appear to be related to the question.

Comment: @yellowantphil users with less than 2k rep can still effectively [suggest a revert to a previous revision](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268339/how-to-handle-edits-you-think-shouldnt-have-been-made/268340#268340)